# How to know that do Firebase JobDispatcher Background job active now programatically.

Tags: android, android-jobscheduler, firebase-job-dispatcher

How to know that do Firebase JobDispatcher Background job active now programmatically for a particular tag.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `adb shell dumpsys activity service GcmService`, which will list all scheduled jobs. Please check your service.

Comment: I guess he was asking how to do that in code, Not possible, afaik, with Firebase dispatcher